# pgadmin3 server connection and authentication error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have recently installed postgresql 9.1 and pgadmin3. But I can't connect to server which I created with this config:

```
name: mydb
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 5432
service: 
Maintenance DB: postgres
username: postgres
password: *
```

According to similar problems I've set my `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` file under ubuntu 12.04 LTS like this:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all             localhost               trust
```

But when I want to connect to the server I get this error:

> Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: When did you create a user `postgre` and assigned it a password?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That was simple after installation of postgresql i should change the postgres user password
and my failure was because of that. The password can simply change through this commands under ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

And then in psql:

```
\password
```

Now enter the new password and re-enter it.
That's OK! then you can simply sign in.
This way there is no need to change the configuration of `pg_hba.conf` file.

In fact i failed to login because of my invalid password!

Comment: hint: get out of postgres by typing `\q`

Answer (score 2):

Seems your DB is configured for "postgres" user and PgAdmin is trying to connect as "postgre" (without s in the end).